# Sort a map in ERB File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a ERB file

```
<%=
require "json"

entries = Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag.map do |tag|
entry = {
  "code"        => tag.code,
  "description" => tag.description,
  "ordinal"     => tag.value,
}
entry
end
JSON.pretty_generate(entries)
%>
```

Is there any way I can sort the Tag.map on the basis of "code" before generating the schema file ??

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is sort an array, whose elements are hash, based on the hash's "code" value.

```
entries.sort { |a, b| a["code"] <=> b["code"] }
```

And also, I would suggest you do this in your controller instead of view.

EDIT:

Or you could do sort the tag first, then mapping them into an Array

```
Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag.sort_by do |a, b|
  a.code <=> b.code
end.map do |tag|
  {
    "code"        => tag.code,
    "description" => tag.description,
    "ordinal"     => tag.value,
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Larry.....was looking for this for last 24hrs....worked like charm :)

Comment: Is there any way we can add this sorting code in the line like

 `"symbols": [ <%= Ci::Canonical::Message::CollectionStrategy.map { |c| %Q{"#{c.name}"} }.join(", ") %> ] `

Comment: I Tried to do above as
 `{
            "name": "language_tag",
            "type": {
              "type": "enum",
              "name": "LanguageTag",
              "symbols": [ <%= Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag.sort_by do |a,b| a.name <=> b.name end.map do { |l| %Q{"#{l.name}"} }.join(", ") %> ]
            } `

I am getting errors.

Comment: Do you want to sort your `Ci::Canonical::Message::CollectionStrategy` or `Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag`?

Comment: I want to sort the values in this array:

 `"symbols": [ <%= Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag.map { |l| %Q{"#{l.name}"} }.join(", ") %> ] `

and I am having multiple array elements in a erb file hence can't use the first approach here.

Comment: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
(erb):61:in `block in generate'
/home/animesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/enumerated_type-0.4.1/lib/enumerated_type.rb:98:in `each'
/home/animesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/enumerated_type-0.4.1/lib/enumerated_type.rb:98:in `each'
(erb):61:in `sort_by'
(erb):61:in `generate'

Comment: I am not sure of what's your question is unless you give me the full codes you are running. My answer is based on your description and my assumption, that you are trying to sort an array with hash elements.

Comment: I have a JSON field named symbols which is taking values as:
 `"symbols": [ <%= Ci::Canonical::Language::Tag.map { |l| %Q{"#{l.name}"} }.join(", ") %> ] `
I am looking to get the values sorted in `|l| `